# Remove untracked file from appearing in git status

Tags: javascript, git, github, terminal

When I do `git status` this appears:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   src/app.js
    modified:   src/view/view.js
    modified:   src/view/layout.js
    modified:   src/view/layout2.js
    modified:   src/view/layout3.js
    modified:   src/view/layout4.js
    modified:   src/view/layout5.js

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ../hidemeplease.json
```

Usually I do `git add -A` to stage all changes at once but this would also add the untracked file. So now I need to painstakingly stage my changes one file at a time.

How do I stop the untracked file from appearing in `git status`? I do not want to delete the file, just ignore it, or have `git status` ignore it.

I tried doing things like:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged hidemeplease.json
```

but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: So this is related to Javascript?

Comment: well the files are javascript files :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *untracked file*, in Git, is a file whose path name does not appear in the index.

Since it's not in the index, you cannot tell `git update-index` to mark the index entry as "assume unchanged" or "skip worktree".  But this is actually *good* news.

If a file is not in the index, `git status` will normally *complain* about it, and `git add .` would *add* it.  To prevent these from occurring, list the file's path name in a `.gitignore` file.

The `.gitignore` file contains a list of path names that Git will shut up about, and not auto-add.  So it should really be called `.git-shut-up-about-these-files-and-do-not-auto-add-them`.  That name is kind of unweildy, though, hence `.gitignore`.

Note that if a file's path name *is* in the index, listing that file in a `.gitignore` file has no effect at all.  That's why the current complaint is good news.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore it you might want to add it to a `.gitignore` file in root of your project or at least in root of your git.

Consider `.gitignore` put in same folder as the file `hidemeplease.json`. Then the former file might have content as simple as this:

```
hidemeplease.json
```